# Row count error in the trigger, Postgres. What I doing wrong?

Tags: postgresql, select, count, triggers, row

Below the trigger ON Before deletion. When I try create this trigger, i get the following error:

ERROR: ОШИБКА:  syntax (near: "*"). Please advise what I am doing wrong!

```
BEGIN
-- Check if it a Root folder
IF OLD.fld_id = 1 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'RootFolder cant be deleted';
ELSE
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;
  
-- Check if folder has children

DECLARE record_count integer;
SELECT COUNT(*) from "Folders" where parent_id = OLD.fld_id INTO record_count;  -->ERROR
IF record_count > 0 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'You cant delete folder as it has children';
ELSE
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;
```

END;

Comment: Please post complete trigger definition and error.

Comment: Not only is your trigger, as posted, incomplete it would never execute anything below the comment to check folder; it has already terminated by then. Either by raising an exception or by return.

Comment: Yeah, you are right will be corrected

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed, I have moved declaration DECLARE record_count integer; before BEGIN

```
DECLARE record_count integer;
BEGIN
    -- Check if it a Root folder
    IF OLD.fld_id = 1 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'RootFolder cant be deleted';
    END IF;
      
    -- Check if folder has children
    SELECT COUNT(*) from "Folders" where parent_id = OLD.fld_id INTO record_count;
    IF record_count > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'You cant delete folder as it has children';
    END IF;
    
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$BODY$;
```